# Reheating turkey

Tags: turkey, reheating

I baked my turkey, cut it off ahead of time, and froze it. When I reheat, should I have it thawed and reheat in slow oven with chicken broth and the drippings from the turkey, or should I reheat in hot oven? It seemed a little dry.

When you reheat, does the turkey get more tender or does it get tough?

Answer (score 1):

Reheating the turkey will not render it more tender, though it can make it more tough if you heat it to a sufficient temperature to begin cooking the proteins again.

I would recommend having the turkey thawed prior to reheating and then warming it in a low oven with some broth as you mention.  Reheating in a hot oven would increase the chances of overheating resulting in dry turkey.

If the drippings form the turkey are not fatty those would be fine to use as well.  If there is a lot of fat in the drippings I would be worried that the turkey may seem greasy when eaten.